# TenserFlow, How to save style transfer model for later use?

Tags: python, tensorflow, style-transfer

I've been using [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/style_transfer#calculate_style) tutorial from TensorFlow's site to create a [script](https://gist.github.com/daniel-keller/1d36b4e225b161cc375a3c26d27e0be6) (python3) that performs a style transfer. I'm trying to train a model on a particular art piece and then apply that style to any random photo. From my understanding of this tutorial the script takes a style image and a content image, runs them through the VGG19 model and spits out a final image (takes about 30min on my machine). But I see no way to save the trained model to apply it to another content photo. This tutorial doesn't use TF's model `fit()`, `predict()`, and `save()` methods like I would expect. It just seems to be applying the prediction to the image as it trains.

How do I save the trained model? Once saved how do I use it on another content photo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `model.save()` method.

Read this tutorial: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize